# How to show plotly graphic on PyQt5 Application

Tags: python, pyqt5, plotly

I try to show the plotly graph in one of application's window.

But this graph does not scale when the window changes.
[image: initial window]
[image: bad window]

How can I fix it?

Here is begin of class Main Window

```
class MainWindow(QWidget, From_Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        
        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.BtnDescribe, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.browser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 170, 444, 596))
```

Here is def plotter, which creates my plot

```
    def plotter(self):
        df_period = self.all_data.loc[:len(self.all_data)-13]
        df_predict = self.all_data.loc[len(self.all_data)-12:]
        fig = go.Figure()
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_period.index, y=df_period['value'], mode='lines', name='value'))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_predict.index, y=df_predict['value'], mode='lines', opacity=0.7, name='value_true'))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_predict.index, y=df_predict['value_predict'], mode='lines',  name='value_predict'))
        self.browser.setHtml(fig.to_html(include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```

I tried to make auto scaled plotly graph but crashed

I expect to have code which gives me auto scaled plotly graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a layout, you cannot set a new one; instead, you need to add the view to it.

Go to Designer, select the parent widget in which you want to add the browser, if it already has an existing layout to which you can add the view, then scroll down to the end of the property editor and get its `layoutName`.

Finally, in the code, use `self.<layout name>.addWidget(self.browser)`.

If it's a grid layout, you need to check the actual row and column of the cell position in which you want to add the view. Eventually, you can add a child layout as a "placeholder" by dragging it from the widget box; in that case, that new layout will be the one to which you'll add the view.

Note that, if you cannot add QWebEngineView from Designer, you can always add a QWidget as a placeholder and then promote it.

Comment: musicamante, thanks for reply.

Comment: I guess my child layout is vlayout, but it doesn' work

Comment: https://ibb.co/crPpSXz

Comment: Sorry, but without knowing the full structure of your UI I cannot just "guess". I've explained the concept, it's up to you to understand how to apply it to your case. Also, please avoid unnecessary comments: 1. this is not a forum, nor a chat; 2. this is not a help desk, we're not here 24/7. 3. continuous comments and pressing for help is just annoying and just results in ignoring.

Comment: I mean I there any methods to auto scale plotly graph with child layout.